# i am having id of input type as unique id so how can i get those unique id into the javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

this is my layout :

```
<input type="button" value="Increase" id="inc" onclick="incNumber()"/> 
<input type="number" id="'.$values["product_id"].'" name="newquan" class="form-control" value="'.$values["product_quantity"].'"> 
<input type="button" value="Increase" id="dec" onclick="decNumber()"/>
```

and here is my javascript

```
function incNumber(){
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value);
    c++;
    document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = c;
}
function decNumber(){
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value);
    b--;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = b;
}
```

and at .getelement byid i want the unique id that are given mention above.

Comment: can you pass the id as a function parameter? ie, `onclick="incNumber('.$values["product_id"].')"` / `function incNumber(product_id){ ... }` / `document.getElementById(product_id).`

Comment: To get it into the javascript, you just ask it nicely

Comment: i have tried that but nothing happen @Sean

Comment: ask it nicely, in which way u mean? @Spangle

Comment: This id "$" could be the issue. "The id value must contain at least one character, and must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.)." Read this up - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: the $ sign is for the unique value that i want here from the id of input type @T.Shah

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you need:

```
function incNumber(){
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value);
    c++;
    var x = document.getElementsByName("newquan")[0]
    document.getElementById(x.id).innerHTML = c;
}
```